# Is there a way to know if a GraphQL request was sent raw or through the Playground?

Tags: javascript, http, graphql, apollo

We are doing some header checking in our Apollo GraphQL application and noticed that when the user sends a request to initially open Playground in the browser, there are no headers present in this request.

The problem is that in our application, all requests are supposed to contain at least some required headers. If these headers are missing, our code flags these requests and determines the request is not genuine. Therefore, a request to open Playground is flagged because it is missing these required headers.

Is there any way to distinguish whether the incoming request is requesting Playground versus a request that is actually making a call for some data? Is there an attribute somewhere?

Comment: what about disabling playground in production?

Comment: We want playground to be open in prod so that users can use it to test their queries and explore the schema. So no we would prefer not to disable it.

Comment: you can add headers in playground console.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary Can't add headers in playground console if the console hasn't yet been initialized/opened/seen.